# Is it a good idea to use a type alias name in python and then declare that as a variable?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-typing

I am looking at code like this:

```
class DeckManager:

   decks: Dict[str, Any]

   def __init__(self, col: a) -> None:

        self.decks = {}
```

Is it correct that decks: Dict[str, Any] is specifying a Type Alias?  If so then does it make sense to use: self.decks later in the code.  Is that not confusing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, `decks` is *not* a type alias. It is a type-annotation. According to [PEP-484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#type-aliases):

> Type aliases are defined by simple variable assignments.

Or according to the [`typing` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#type-aliases):

> A type alias is defined by assigning the type to the alias.

So assigning to a variable anything that would be a valid type annotation is a type alias:

```
decks = Dict[str, Any]
```

This way `decks` would be a type alias.

But when you use the colon, you are *annotating* that variable, not creating a type alias:

```
decks: Dict[str, Any]
```

According to Python's type annotation conventions, you've simply annotated the `decks` attribute for `DeckManager` instances to have type `Dict[str, Any]`.

Comment: It seems that `decks: TypeAlias = dict[str, Any]` is now the way to [alias types](https://peps.python.org/pep-0613/).